# globally scoped variable not returning from function

Tags: php

I think I've been staring at this too long, but why won't `$sum` *echo 23*?
(I'm aiming to have a global scoped `$sum` injected in to a function and returned when the function is complete)

```
<?php

$sum = 0;

function find_divisible() {

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

        if ($i % 5 == 0) {
            echo "<br>".' $sum is equal to '.$sum.' and $i is equal to '.$i;
            $sum += $i;
        }elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
            echo "<br>".' $sum is equal to '.$sum.' and $i is equal to '.$i;
            $sum += $i;
        }else {
            echo "<br/>$i is not divisible...";
        }

    }

    return $sum;

}


find_divisible($sum);
echo "<br>";
echo $sum;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your code you have 3 main errors/problems:

1. You forgot the following line in your function (at the top)

```
global $sum;
```

2. You return `$sum`, but you don't assign the function call to a variable, so you can remove it

3. You pass `$sum` as an argument to the function, but the function doesn't takes any arguments, so delete all parameters in the function call

But to archive your goal i see 3(4) different ways!

1. With global variables (Which you do now (But i wouldn't recommend that, because later you get really confused and encapsulation? you can forget that if you use global))

2. You can pass the variable as argument, your code would looks something like this:

```
$sum = 0;

function find_divisible($sum) {

    //Code

    return $sum;

}

$sum = find_divisible($sum);
echo $sum;
```

3. You can pass the variable by reference, your code would looks something like this:

```
$sum = 0;

function find_divisible(&$sum) {
                      //^ See here

    //Code

}

find_divisible($sum);
echo $sum;
```

(4). You don't have to use any parameter if you say `$sum` is always 0 and you just return `$sum` and assign it to a variable, your code would looks something like this:

```
function find_divisible() {

    $sum = 0;

    //Code

    return $sum;

}

$sum = find_divisible();
echo $sum;
```

(Hope this answer helps you, i think it's always good to see different ways/solutions)

Comment: @Medri No problem, happens to everyone :D Have a nice day

Comment: You should really stay away from the `global` keyword as it ruins encapsulation and **can** cause a lot of headaches in the long run. Better to pass the variable as an argument in the function.

Comment: @CarlMarkham agree with you, also since i think `$sum` is every time 0 OP  doesn't even have to pass as an argument, he just can declare it in the function. The only thing i could think off, which is worth as an argument would be the max for the for loop

Comment: Sorry @Rizier123 but keeping the down vote as long as `global` stays as the top solution in your answer

Comment: @BrokenBinary What's that for a cheap promotion?!

Comment: @CarlMarkham Thanks, at least you explain why you down vote! (With this i can work and make the answer better)

Comment: @Medri BTW: You can accept the how helped you the most and solved your problem! (Also i would recommend you to take a quick 2min tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You still specify the use of `global` though @Rizier123 :P Although it is fine and works it isn't up to today's coding standards and isn't needed at all when there are much better (and safer) methods of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Rizier123 I think I accepted it right, I really appreciate your help in everything!

Comment: @CarlMarkham I just wanted first to correct the current code from OP and then show different/other ways, but as long as someone says why he down Votes, i can live with it :D

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `$sum` as a reference like this:

```
function find_divisible(&$sum) {
    // code here
}
```

But you wouldn't need to return it from the function. Any changes made to it in the function would be made to the original variable you passed into `find_divisible($sum)`

Comment: I like this too! Much appreciated! Actually, you showed me that I didn't have to do the return either.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the global keyword.

```
global $sum;
```

Although, I'd recommend taking it in as a parameter like so.

```
function find_divisible($sum) {
    ...
}
```